# Determinate the discontinuities of the function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Determinate the discontinuities of the function $f:R \to R$,$$f(x)=[x]\sin ({\pi x})$$I've seen the graph and it is clear that there are no discontinuities but how do we determine that without drawing a graph?

Comment: What is $[x]$? Do you mean $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: As usual: Argue that it is continuous on intervals $[k,k+1]$ and compute the limits at the boundary.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mean the integer part of x

Comment: @Smurf Shoult i compute the limit to k and k+1?

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is not an integer it is clear that $f$ is continuous at $x$. If $x$ is an integer $k$ then $f(k)=0$ and $[x]\sin (\pi x) \to 0$ as $x \to k$ ( because $[x]$ remains bounded as $x \to k$ and $\sin (\pi x) \to 0$) so $f$ is continuous at $x$. Hence $f$ is continuous at all points.